# Having an issue creating log files

Tags: powershell, scripting

I wanted to see if I could get some assistance writing some information to a log file.  In the example below, I am using echo, but I have also tried write-host.  I am trying to get a CSV file with some text and a comma and then my environment variable.  It seems to work great on screen with the Write-Host, but when I dump it to a log, the $variable always seems to drop to the line below instead of staying on the same line as the text in quotes.

```
 $Dude = "UserName"

 Try 
 { 
    Set-Mailbox $Dude -AntispamBypassEnabled $true -ErrorAction Stop -WarningVariable Warn 
 } 
 Catch 
 {
   echo "Change Failed" $Dude >> c:\scripts\text.log
   Exit 2
 }

 if ($Warn) 
 { 
    echo "Change Succeeded, but no changes were made." $Dude >> c:\cripts\text.log
    Exit 1
 }
 else 
 { 
    echo "Your change was successful." $Dude >> c:\scripts\text.log 
    Exit 0
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring your variable inside the double quotes. Like this:

```
echo "Hello $dude" >> file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is simply an alias for the `Write-Output` command. The behavior you're seeing is happening, because you're writing out two different objects to the file. The first item is a `String`, and the second is the `$Dude` variable (which incidentally also points to a String).

To avoid confusion in the future, I would recommend building your log message in its entirety first, and then writing it to the output file using one of the following options:

- `Set-Content`
- `Out-File`
- `[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText()`

Here's an example:

```
$LogMessage = '{0}: Operation completed successfully, but no changes were made for user: {1}' -f (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'), $Dude;
Set-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\Mailboxes.log -Value $LogMessage;
```

**FYI**: `Write-Host` does not output any information to the pipeline, and merely writes text to the console. When you use the `>>` redirection operator, with `Write-Host` on the left, you are basically outputting "nothing" to the target file.

ps. I would also recommend coming up with a clearer log message than "Change Succeeded, but no changes were made." That would be rather confusing to someone who doesn't understand what the program is doing.